# Is it possible to use safari extension in ios application

Tags: ios, macos, ios-app-extension, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am developing an iOS app with app extension feature.But using "App Extension" we could not customize safari content.Anyone having idea about "Safari Extension".Can we use safari extension in ios app?

Answer (score 0):

Safari App Extensions are desktop only and have to bundled with a [containing macOS app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension). On iOS you can have [Content Blockers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1).

Comment: Desktop also has Content Blockers.